# Import Ansible collection in playbook locally from the current folder without packing or galaxy

Tags: ansible, yaml, roles

```
.
├── test
│   └── ansible_poc_collection
│       ├── docs
│       ├── galaxy.yml
│       ├── plugins
│       │   └── README.md
│       ├── README.md
│       └── roles
│           └── testrole
│               └── tasks
│                   └── main.yml
└── test-play.yml
```

`galaxy.yml` contains namespace and name:

```
namespace: test
name: ansible_poc_collection
```

In `test-play.yml` I import the testrole from the collection [like this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/collections_using.html#using-collections-in-playbooks):

```
- hosts: all
  collections:
   - test.ansible_poc_collection
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: testrole
```

But it throws an error that the role could not be found:

```
ERROR! the role 'testrole' was not found in /home/user/tests/ansible-poc-collection/roles:/home/user/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/user/tests/ansible-poc-collection

The error appears to be in '/home/user/user/ansible-poc-collection/test-play.yml': line 6, column 15, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    - import_role:
        name: testrole
              ^ here
```

Tried to create a top level folder `collections` and moved the collection there so that it's located in `collections/test/ansible_poc_collection`, same error. Also when refering the full name with collection namespace/name:

```
- import_role:
    name: test.ansible_poc_collection.testrole
```

Another non-working approach was setting `COLLECTIONS_PATHS` so that it points to the root directory of my collection (containing the `test` namespace folder):

```
COLLECTIONS_PATHS=/home/user/tests/ansible-poc-collection/collections ansible-playbook -i 127.0.0.1, test-play.yml
```

How can I import a collection locally without building an archive and using the Ansible Galaxy?

Used version is 2.9.6 (latest stable at time of writing)

Comment: Alright, this is basically a workaround. Copy just the directories needed and dependent directories adjacent to the playbook (from the collection directory). 
\n Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout
\n
.
├── plugins
│   └── README.md
├── roles
│   └── testrole
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── test-play.yml

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is basically a workaround.

Copy just the directories needed and dependent directories adjacent to the playbook (from the collection directory).

Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout

```
.
├── plugins
│   └── README.md
├── roles
│   └── testrole
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── test-play.yml
```